# Cannot update Entity data model from database due to TNS error

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to update my Entity data model from the database. Earlier today, I ran my app just fine and was able to access the database, as I have a tnsnames.ora file that I copied and pasted into my project folder. Then, when i was trying to open my edmx file, I was getting a message along the lines of:

"The ADO.NET provider 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded"

I noticed that my machine didn't have ODAC for Visual Studio installed. So I went ahead and did that. Now, I can open my edmx file just fine, but my wizard is failing to connect to the database:

"ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

I don't think I've touched my tnsnames.ora file since this morning. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured the problem out.

I had to copy the tnsnames.ora file over to where i installed Oracle/client_1/Network/Admin, AND get the sqlnet.ora file in that same location.