# Entity Framework Wizard not showing new tables added in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, visual-studio

This is relevant to yesterday's question: [Cannot update Entity data model from database due to TNS error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41709041/1287126)

I've got 32-bit ODAC installed so now I'm able to see my .edmx file just fine. But now I'm trying to update my data models from an Oracle database. I select the connection in my config file, connect to it, and when it prompts me to add/update/delete tables, there are no tables that come up. I can't select any checkboxes on the add screen either, and nothing happens when I press Finish. I've also tried deleting the .edmx file and generate a new one from the database, but again, no tables show up at all when I try to add all of them and the checkbox cannot be selected.

I checked another project that uses Entity with Microsoft SQL Server and it looks like it works just fine. I'm completely baffled why this doesn't work...

I believe my connection string in my web.config file is right since I'm able to run the app just fine. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:** I checked the Delete tab, and it shows all of the tables in my model. I know that when I go to this tab, it displays all of the models that are currently not in the database. All of the models in my .edmx file that are showing up under the Delete tab are in fact, in the database. Weird...

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to switch the database over to MS SQL server. Didn't exactly solve the problem, but I'm on a deadline and seemed like it's unsolvable (for the time being).